# Android/Java - Bluetooth RSSI updating in ArrayList without access to it

Tags: java, android, arraylist, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

When scanning for Bluetooth devices, I am attempting to capture each unique device in an ArrayList by their MAC addresses. I want to connect to the strongest signal RSSI in the list afterwards. For some reason, the RSSI keeps updating in the below code. The ONLY time that data is placed into an ArrayList is when the MAC is not contained in another list.

Basically, I check the mac address I scan against what is in a list, and if it is not in that list, I add device information into a different ArrayList.

Why is the RSSI still updating in the deviceArray ArrayList??

```
// Device Discovery
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback leScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, final byte[] scanRecord) {

        if (device.getName() != null){
            if (DEVICE_NAME.equals(device.getName())){

                deviceInfo[0] = device.getName();
                deviceInfo[1] = device.getAddress();
                deviceInfo[2] = Integer.toString(rssi);

                // Add device info if MAC address is not located
                if (!MACAddresses.contains(deviceInfo[1])){
                    deviceArray.add(deviceInfo);
                    MACAddresses.add(deviceInfo[1]);
                    Log.e("MAC ADDRESS ADDING", "ADDING " + deviceInfo[1]);
                }

                // TODO remove this logging info
                for(int i = 0; i < deviceArray.size(); i++){
                    Log.e("Bluetooth Devices",
                            "Array Length = " + deviceArray.size() + ", "
                            + deviceArray.get(i)[0] + ", "
                            + deviceArray.get(i)[1] + ", "
                            + deviceArray.get(i)[2]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Now, please look at the output below. The ArrayList size is 2, and we only have 2 MAC addresses (as we should), but the RSSI changes from time to time. Notice that there are 3 RSSI values (-41, -47, and -48) where there should only be 2 values. On top of this, it seems odd to me that these ArrayList items are not being printed out one after another. If one MAC address is A, and the other is B, they should be printing out as AB, AB, AB, AB, but they are more like AB BA AB BA, and at one point there is an AAAA.

```
E/MAC ADDRESS ADDING: ADDING 00:A0:50:CC:4B:9B
E/Bluetooth Devices: Array Length = 1, MyDeviceName, 00:A0:50:CC:4B:9B, -41
E/MAC ADDRESS ADDING: ADDING 00:A0:50:12:14:96
E/Bluetooth Devices: Array Length = 2, MyDeviceName, 00:A0:50:12:14:96, -48
E/Bluetooth Devices: Array Length = 2, MyDeviceName, 00:A0:50:12:14:96, -48
E/Bluetooth Devices: Array Length = 2, MyDeviceName, 00:A0:50:CC:4B:9B, -41
E/Bluetooth Devices: Array Length = 2, MyDeviceName, 00:A0:50:CC:4B:9B, -41
E/Bluetooth Devices: Array Length = 2, MyDeviceName, 00:A0:50:12:14:96, -48
E/Bluetooth Devices: Array Length = 2, MyDeviceName, 00:A0:50:12:14:96, -48
E/Bluetooth Devices: Array Length = 2, MyDeviceName, 00:A0:50:CC:4B:9B, -41
E/Bluetooth Devices: Array Length = 2, MyDeviceName, 00:A0:50:CC:4B:9B, -41
E/Bluetooth Devices: Array Length = 2, MyDeviceName, 00:A0:50:12:14:96, -47
E/Bluetooth Devices: Array Length = 2, MyDeviceName, 00:A0:50:12:14:96, -48
E/Bluetooth Devices: Array Length = 2, MyDeviceName, 00:A0:50:CC:4B:9B, -41
E/Bluetooth Devices: Array Length = 2, MyDeviceName, 00:A0:50:CC:4B:9B, -41
E/Bluetooth Devices: Array Length = 2, MyDeviceName, 00:A0:50:CC:4B:9B, -41
E/Bluetooth Devices: Array Length = 2, MyDeviceName, 00:A0:50:CC:4B:9B, -41
E/Bluetooth Devices: Array Length = 2, MyDeviceName, 00:A0:50:12:14:96, -47
```

Further down in the output that I didn't paste in, I actually see more RSSI values (-58 and -53). I just don't understand how these can even make it into the ArrayList if i'm not adding the item once per MAC. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out. I'm not good with memory locations, so I made a mistake in my code. In the class variables, I was creating a string array:

```
String[] deviceInfo = new String[3];
```

However, this method was using the same memory location and was able to overwrite the data. Furthermore, my device array was actually storing 2 of the same MAC addresses, which was not helpful either. This is how I later spotted the issue.

At any rate, I had to declare a new String array inside the callback method each loop to be able to obtain a new memory location.